# Where does business logic belong in the MVC pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, edmx

Say I have a person table in a database. Whenever a new person is added into the database, a pdf will be generated and emailed to someone.

Does this logic go into the model, so all the application does is pass in the data to insert the new person, and the model also handles the pdf and email?

Or does this logic go into the controller?

If this should go into the model, and I am using entity framework, how do I do this? Create a .cs class that wraps the `.edmx` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that you would not want to muck up the controller with that kind of logic. Things that belong in the controller would be defining models that are going to get passed to the view or turning validations on or off. There are several other view related things that the controller should control but that is just a couple. The general point that I am trying to make is that the controller is responsible for populating models by calling services or mocked repositories and then passing those models to the view.

To do what you are explaining I would add a service layer that sits above the data access layer (dal - where your EDMX and repositories sit). Inside that service layer is where I would call the methods or services to generate the pdf and send emails.

The repositories and data access layer should only be concerned with querying the database and retrieving records. That is regardless of what ORM or data access tool you use. the retrieved records are passed to the service layer where you can perform actions against the data (such as validations or sending out pdf's) and then the presentation layer is returned whatever format of the records that it needs to display it in the view. The controller doesn't perform any logical action against the retrieved data but instead just hands it off to the view.

If you would like some more details about the architecture layout that I have described then I would be happy to give you more insight into it.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the help. one more question though about where logic should go, the answer might just be the service layer again but i want to be sure. 
Say in the controller I want to get a person with the ID of ten to pass to the view.
I want to get the data in the database from the persons table, but i also want to get data from an API call to finish filling the model, say... a horoscope for today for the person. Where does that go?
Thanks.

Comment: @user1308743 That would depend on how your API functions. You have a repository or some method that accepts personId = 10 and retrieves that record from the person table. That record is passed back to the controller in some fashion. From there you pass that person record to the view via a view model. Then in the view your API component should request some type of parameter such as "astrological_sign" which the retrieved record will provide. That API goes out and gets the horoscope for that sign and displays it. So you wouldn't do that in the service layer since it is not your API.

Comment: @user1308743 if it is your custom API and you store that horoscope data in your database then it should be a subsequent service call that retrieves the horoscope based on the person record and then have that horoscope data assigned the the view model along with the person details as attributes.